# chosen jquery plugin for multiselect list not showing value in edited form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-chosen

I m using chosen jquery plugin for multiselect list.my problem is it is not showing selected value in edited form.

my controler code is

```
ArrayList selectedrole = new ArrayList();
foreach (var role in employee.CompanyRoles)
{
    selectedrole.Add(role.CompanyRoleId.ToString());
}

[ViewBag.CompanyRoleId = new SelectList(CompanyRole, "CompanyRoleId", "RoleName", selectedrole);]
```

my view code

```
<div class="editor-label">
    Role
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.ListBox("emprole", ViewBag.CompanyRoleId as MultiSelectList , new
                 {
                     @class = "chzn-select",
                     data_placeholder = "Choose  Role...",
                     style="width:350px;" 
                 })
</div>
```

and my script

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });
```

can any body tell me what i m doing wrong it is not showing selected value when form is displaying in edited mode.

Comment: When the form is submitted what values are posted back to the controller? How do you handle them? It sounds like the code you posted is fine and the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: thanks for the reply value are posted fine and save to the database but when i edit these value it will not show already selected values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code below `selectedrole` is expected to be of the same type as the objects in `CompanyRoles`. It also only allows one item to be selected.

```
ViewBag.CompanyRoleId = new SelectList(CompanyRoles, "CompanyRoleId", "RoleName", selectedrole);
```

You need to use `MultiSelectList` instead.

```
ViewBag.CompanyRoleId = new MultiSelectList(CompanyRoles, "CompanyRoleId", "RoleName", employee.CompanyRoles.ToList());
```